# map::lower_bound that returns a map

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a function that does the same thing as `map::lower_bound` except it returns a new sub-map and not an iterator?

**Edit:** The function should return a sub-map which contains all the values for which the key is **equal to, or greater** than a certain value (which is given as input to the function).

Comment: What do you expect such a submap to contain?

Comment: Regarding your edit: Wouldn't you need `upper_bound()` for this?

Comment: `lower_bound` will find the first element that isn't less than the given key, which will obviously include the key itself. `upper_bound` will exclude the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
template< typename K, typename V >
std::map<K,V> equal_or_greater(const std::map<K,V>& original, const K& k)
{
   return std::map<K,V>( original.lower_bound(k), original.end() );
}
```

***Edit:*** It seems you actually want `upper_bound()` instead of `lower_bound()`.

Comment: @Marcelo: Actually, that `blah` was no accident. I find it hard to come up with a good name for a function creating a map according to some specifics. `equal_or_greater` sounds like a comparator function, not like one that creates a map.

Comment: Fair point, sbi. I personally don't mind overloading names this way since the parameters tend to resolve the confusion, and humans are pretty good at handling ambiguity anyway.